# Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException & Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using Eclipse.i have imported a materialDesign project in my eclipse but i cannot run the project.The problems are

**1**.`Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Workspace\AndroidMaterialNavigationDrawer\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist`

**2**.`Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output.`

[Here Is the Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWksG.jpg)

Please Help me to run the **MaterialDesignNavigationDrawer** project in my Eclipse.
Here is the Project https://github.com/manishkpr/AndroidMaterialDesignNavigationDrawer

Need Solution!!Tnx
I didn't use any kind of code to read data from file..

Comment: Please show your code where you want to access the file.

Comment: I just Imported this project From the github link and there is no code where i want to access file.. u can check the project from the above github link. TNX

Answer (score 0):

You are just trying to read a file that doesn't exist. The resource folder is not there, however there is a res folder. You should look carefully and see if there is a typo where you tried to access the file.

Comment: I just Imported this project From the github link and there is no java code where i want to access file.. u can check the project from the above github link.  in the eclipse problems the error location in unknown :( What should i do now ??